# Groupby sum and difference of rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Metric': ['Total Assets', 'Total Promo', 'Total Assets', 'Total Int'],
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'AA'],
    'Risk': ['High', 'High','Low', 'High'],
    '202101': [ 130, 200, 190, 210], 
    '202102': [ 130, 200, 190, 210],
    '202103': [ 130, 200, 190, 210],})
```

I would like to groupby `Product` and `Risk` and sum the entries in `Total Assets` and `Total Promo` and subtract the result from the entries in `Total Int`. I could multiply all rows with  `Total Int` by -1 and sum the result. But I wanted to know if there was a direct way to do so.

```
df.groupby(['Product', 'Risk']).sum()
```

The actual dataset is large and it would introduce complexity to multiply certain rows by -1

The output would look like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Product': ['AA', 'BB'],
    'Risk': ['High', 'Low'],
    '202101': [ 120, 190], 
    '202102': [ 120, 190],
    '202103': [ 120, 190],})
```

Comment: I think multiplying the value to subtract by -1 is an efficient and explicit solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply by -1 your `Total Int` rows:

```
df.loc[df['Metric'] == 'Total Int', df.select_dtypes('number').columns] *= -1

# OR

df.loc[df['Metric'] == 'Total Int', df.filter(regex=r'\d{6}').columns] *= -1
```

```
>>> df.groupby(['Product', 'Risk']).sum()
              202101  202102  202103
Product Risk
AA      High     120     120     120
BB      Low      190     190     190
```

Comment: Although I think this might be the best solution, this was explicitely rejected by OP ;) (*The actual dataset is large and it would introduce complexity to multiply certain rows by -1*)

Comment: Nevertheless, likely the simplest and most explicit, if not most efficient!

Comment: Thanks @mozway and corralien. The names of columns are in the yyyymm format. I edited by question. How could I use the df.filter operation with those column names

Comment: I updated my answer. Use `select_dtypes('number')`

Comment: `like="2021"` or `regex="\d{6}"`

Answer (score 1):

In your actual dataset, do you have any groups that only have one row? The following solution will work if all groups have greater than one row, so that `diff()`, doesn't return `nan`. This is thy the second row of output is not in there, but I imagine your groups have more than one row in your large dataset.

IIUC, create a series `s` that differentiates the two groups and take the `diff` after a `groupby` of the `sum`:

```
 import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'Metric': ['Total Assets', 'Total Promo', 'Total Assets', 'Total Int'],
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'AA'],
    'Risk': ['High', 'High','Low', 'High'],
    'Col1': [ 130, 200, 190, 210], 
    'Col2': [ 130, 200, 190, 210],
    'Col3': [ 130, 200, 190, 210],})

s = np.where(df['Metric'].isin(['Total Assets', 'Total Promo']), 'B', 'A')

cols = ['Product', 'Risk']
(df.groupby(cols + [s]).sum()
   .groupby(cols).diff()
   .dropna().reset_index().drop('level_2', axis=1))

Out[1]: 
  Product  Risk   Col1   Col2   Col3
0      AA  High  120.0  120.0  120.0
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this as a solution?

```
(df.
 melt(['Metric', 'Product', 'Risk']).
 pivot(index=['Product', 'Risk', 'variable'], columns= 'Metric', values = 'value').
 assign(Total = lambda df: df['Total Assets'].fillna(0)+df['Total Promo'].fillna(0) - df['Total Int'].fillna(0)).
 drop(columns = ['Total Assets', 'Total Promo', 'Total Int']).
 reset_index().
 pivot(index=['Product', 'Risk'], columns= 'variable', values = 'Total')
 )
```